# How to vertical-align an alternate text within a floated image?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

Having tried some of the solutions relating to vertical align, I don't seem to be able to solve this. Not sure if anyone can help me on this. All I want is to position the alternate text in the middle of an empty image.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="viewport">
 <a href="#">
  <img src="http://yahoo.com/" alt="no image" />
 </a>
 <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css code:

```
.viewport {
 background: #bbb;
 width: 350px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 5px;
}

.viewport img {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #000;
 text-align: center;
}

.viewport div {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for taking your time to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edit 2017: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) FTW (probably with `a` both as a flex item (its container having default vertical/second axis `align-items: stretch`) and a flex container (vertical alignment is then achieved with `flex-direction:column` and `justify-content: whatisneeded`)

I believe `@alt` has the height of its content, far less than 100px.

By fixing a **line-height** equal to height, `vetical-align` will do what you intend it to do.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/Xevph/

Comment: Would you mind helping me with [this bounty question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10672586/948920)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on chrome.  But in case anyone cares, looks like you can add a blank space at the start of the alt text to push it over a little...

Comment: OK in Chrome 42 on Vista, except the broken image icon that seems to push alternative text horizontally by a few pixels. @KVISH Did you test in Safari 8.1 or older?

Comment: no good if line wraps

Answer (score 4):

no you cant do that. But you can change the color and display properties like

```
img[alt]{
color:red;
 display:none;
}
```

Here is a cool tip, first check if file exist i-e the image you are loading is avaialble or not if not then show up a div with the alt attribute text in that DIV.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The attribute selector (square brackets) does not select the attribute itself but all elements that have the attribute set. See: https://www.w3.org/People/howcome/foo.dir/selector.html